# send over IP immediately on different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, tcp

This is probably impossible, but i'm going to ask anyways.  I have a multi-threaded program (server) that receives a request on a thread dedicated to IP communications and then passes it on to worker threads to do work, then I have to send a reply back with answers to the client and send it when it is actually finished, with as little delay as possible.  Currently I am using a consumer/producer pattern and placing replies on a queue for the IP Thread to take off and send back to my client. This, however gives me no guarantee about WHEN this is going to happen, as the IP thread might not get scheduled any time soon, I cannot know.  This makes my client, that is blocking for this call, think that the request has failed, which is obviously not the point.

Due to the fact I am unable to make changes in the client, I need to solve this sending issue on my side, the problem that I'm facing is that I do not wish to start sharing my IP object (currently only on 1 thread) with the worker threads, as then things get overly complicated.  I wondered if there is some way I can use thread sync mechanisms to ensure that the moment my worker thread is finished, the IP thread will execute my send the reply back to the client?

Will manual/autoreset events do this for me or are these not guaranteed to wake up the thread immediately?

Comment: You didn't mention your platform. I suppose thread synchronization mechanisms vary strongly, since they are not defined by the standard.

Comment: Operating System: Windows Only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it sent *immediately*, your best bet is to bite the bullet and start sharing the connection object. Lock it before accessing it, of course, and be sure to think about what you'll do if the send buffer is already full (the connection thread will need to deal with sending the portion of the message that didn't fit the first time, or the worker thread will be blocked until the client accepts some of the data you've sent). This may not be too difficult if your clients only have one request running at a time; if that's the case you can simply pass ownership of the client object to the worker thread when it begins processing, and pass it back when you're done.

Another option is using real-time threads. The details will vary between operating systems, but in most cases, if your thread has a high enough priority, it will be scheduled in immediately if it becomes ready to run, and will preempt all other threads with lower priority until done. On Linux this can be done with the [SCHED_RR](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_sched_setscheduler.htm) priority class, for example. However, this can negatively impact performance in many cases; as well as crashing the system if your thread gets into an infinite loop. It also usually requires administrative rights to use these scheduling classes.

That said, if scheduling takes long enough that the client times out, you might have some other problems with load. You should also really put a number on how fast the response needs to be - there's no end of things you can do if you want to speed up the response, but there'll come a point where it doesn't matter anymore (do you need response in the tens of ms? single-digit ms? hundreds of microseconds? single-digit microseconds?).

Answer (score 2):

There is no synchronization mechanism that will wake a thread immediately. When a synchronization mechanism for which a thread is waiting is signaled, the thread is placed in a ready queue for its priority class. It can be starved there for several seconds before it's scheduled (Windows does have mechanisms that deal with starvation over 3-4 second intervals).

I think that for out-of-band, critical communications you can have a higher priority thread to which you can enqueue the reply message and wake it up (with a condition variable, MRE or any other synchronization mechanism). If that thread has higher priority than the rest of your application's threads, waking it up will immediately effect a context switch.